# Directive scope not getting updated in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My directive's controller is not getting updated with the scope that was set using the '=' two-way-binding.

Here is my directive:

```js
.directive('navigation', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        selection: '=?selectedItem',
        goforward: '&onForward'
      },
      controller: function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.hideForward = !vm.selection
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '<button ng-hide="vm.hideForward" ng-click="vm.goforward()">Continue</button>'
    };
  });
```

Here is my html file where I use the directive:

```
<div class='product' ng-click='ctrl.selectedItem = true'>item</div>
<navigation on-forward="ctrl.goForward()" selected-item='ctrl.selectedItem'></navigation>
```

note: the ctrl.goForward() works just fine.

The vm.selectedItem in the html's controller is only set to true once the product div is clicked.

I expected the `ctrl.selectedItem` to get passed into my directive's controller and modify the `vm.hideForward` value, except this is not happening.

I want to be able to change whether the navigation directive is visible and/or active depending on variables that are passed into it from whatever controller's scope I used my directive in.

If I place a `<div>{{vm.selectedItem}}</div>` inside my directive's template, that does print out properly depending on how `ctrl.selectedItem` that value changes. My issue is getting the directive's controller to change as well.

How am I setting up this scope binding improperly? I am using angular 1.5.3

Comment: Usually it doesn't make sense, but I have encountered it few times. Using ng-hide sometimes do not work as expected. Have u tried using ng-if instead in your directive's template

Comment: ctrl.selectedItem is a variable from the present controller. So while passing it as attribute, you need to pass it as '{{ctrl.selectedItem}}"

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the double brackets for binding a function to ng-click, use `ng-click="vm.goforward()"`

Pass the function to the directive as `on-forward="ctrl.goForward"`, if you use parenthesis you will be passing the result of the function call instead.

Also for, `ng-click='ctrl.selectedItem === true'` you should use `ng-click='ctrl.selectedItem = true'` to set the value,  as === is a comparison operator.

Comment: I fixed the {{}} issue and the === issue. But I do believe I should be passing the function call, and not just the function itself. I'm not sure entirely why, because as you suggest, passing the function does make more sense, but that is how it's done in [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and on [egghead tutorials](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding)

Comment: if you pass the fonction you have to call it in your directive. If you want to do as it is done in ng-click you have to $eval the expression every time you need

Comment: Looks like you're right about passing the function like that, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl.selectedItem seems to be a variable from the present controller. So while passing it as attribute, you need to pass it as '{{ctrl.selectedItem}}" .

Try using:

```
**<navigation on-forward="ctrl.goForward()" selected-item='{{ctrl.selectedItem}}'></navigation>**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.directive('navigation', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        selection: '=selectedItem',
        goforward: '&onForward'
      },
      controller: function(scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.hideForward = !scope.selection
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '<button ng-hide="vm.hideForward" ng-click="vm.goforward()">Continue</button>'
    };
  });
```